# SQL Server CE - Problems updating table

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I'm sure my question has been answered many times on the internet, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I'm working on VB.NET and my database is a SQL Server Compact `.SDF` file. The following is my method of opening the database.

```
Private Shared Sub OpenDatabase(ByVal tablename As String)
    If _DBLoaded Then Return

    '// open database connection
    conn = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source = giadatabase.sdf")
    conn.Open()

    '// create command for making extracting data
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & tablename & "]"

    '// setup database adapter
    da = New SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd)

    '// create command for inserting/updating database
    cb = New SqlCeCommandBuilder(da)

    '// load dataset
    ds = New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds)

    '// get the relevant table
    dt = ds.Tables(0)

    _DBLoaded = True
End Sub
```

I run this sub when my application starts. I believe that database needs to be opened just once. Constantly reopening of database will cause performance problems to my application (correct me if I'm wrong).

For loading data in my list object I use the following:

```
Public Shared Function GetList() As List(Of DatabaseListObject)
    OpenDatabase("TestTable")

    '// Make a list of items in database
    Dim ret As New List(Of DatabaseListObject)
    For Each dRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
        ret.Add(New DatabaseListObject(dRow("ID"), dRow("LongName"), dRow("ShortName")))
    Next

    Return ret
End Function
```

So my `GetList` function ensures database is already open, and database is always opened once a lifetime of my application. My list object is filled with data from the above function.

This is how I make changes to my database:

```
Public Shared Function AddItem(LongName As String, ShortName As String) As DatabaseListObject
    '// Make changes
    Dim row = dt.NewRow()
    row("LongName") = TimeOfDay.ToString
    row("ShortName") = ShortName
    dt.Rows.Add(row)

    da.Update(ds, dt.TableName)

    Dim newcmd = conn.CreateCommand
    newcmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY;"
    Dim newID As Integer = newcmd.ExecuteScalar()

    Dim item As New DatabaseListObject(newID, LongName, ShortName)
    Return item
End Function
```

Now I assume database is correctly updated from the above code. The `ID` column in my table is the autonumber. Problem occurs when I call the `GetList` function after adding a row. System throws error that the newly added row's ID column is NULL. Whereas it should be automatically added number. When I restart the application, i.e. the database is opened from scratch, then the `GetList` shows the autonumber properly.

Obviously the table's `ID` column is not getting filled-in with the autonumber when I'm adding a new row. So I need suggestions here. Should I always open the database from scratch whenever I call the `GetList` (which will be called frequently in my app). If not the entire database then which codes should be called at least to properly refresh the table without causing much performance problems to the application.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT @@IDENTITY will only Work on the same open Connection object, and the DataAdapter opens and Closes its own connection, you must use plain ADO.NET (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery) or implemet extra code as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/09/15/inserting-master-detail-data-into-a-sql-server-compact-edition-database.aspx

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I'm not having a problem with SELECT @@IDENTITY. That is working fine for me in the `AddItem` function. The problem that I face is that after the `AddItem` function is done with adding data to the table, the table does not get refreshed with the new autonumber. It fails when I call dRow("ID") in the `GetList` function to update my list. I'm not having any controls that are bound to this database.